# Another Rock, Paper, Scissors

Tags: javascript

I'm just trying to build the first two steps of my r/p/s game, and here is my coding so far.  It is giving me the response "Syntax error: unexpected token else" and I cannot for the life of me figure out why...

```
var compare = function (choice1, choice2) {
    if (choice1===choice2) {
        return "The result is a tie!";
    }
    else if (choice1 === "rock") {
        if (choice2 === "scissors")
            return "Rock wins";
    } else {
        return "Paper wins";
    }
    else if (choice1 === "paper") {
        if (choice2 === "rock")
            return "paper wins";
    } else {
        return "scissors wins";
    }
}
```

Comment: you cant have else than an else if, or multiple `} else {`, else needs to be the last block

Comment: Because you have `if` then `else if` then `else` followed by an `else if`. You can't have an `else` case directly after another `else`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You closed the main if/else chain with your paper wins section, I believe you meant to attach that else to the inner if/else as below.

In the paper section you had the same thing, I fixed that instance as well.  From here you should be able to add the final `if(choice1 === "scissors")` segment.

```
var compare = function (choice1, choice2) {
    if (choice1===choice2) {
        return "The result is a tie!";
    }
    else if (choice1 === "rock") {
        if (choice2 === "scissors") return "Rock wins";
        else return "Paper Wins";
    } 
    else if (choice1 === "paper") {
        if (choice2 === "rock") return "Paper wins";
        else return "Scissors wins";
    } 
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the help.  I didn't know you could even add an "else" without its own brackets {...}, let alone write "else return" together with nothing in between.  (I'm very newb) So thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this for you:

```
var compare = function (choice1, choice2) {
    if (choice1===choice2) {
        return "The result is a tie!";
    }
    else if (choice1 === "rock") {
        if (choice2 === "scissors") {
            return "Rock wins";
        } else {
            return "Paper wins";
        }
    }
    else if (choice1 === "paper") {
        if (choice2 === "rock") {
            return "paper wins";
        } else {
           return "scissors wins";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got a muddle of ifs and elses!

I believe specifically, you've got `if (choice2 === "scissors")` without curly braces, which is fine, except then you closed the brackets you never opened with an `} else {`. You should indent properly, it will help you see why you might have run into an issue.

```
var compare = function (choice1, choice2) {
    if (choice1===choice2) {
        return "The result is a tie!";
    }
    else if (choice1 === "rock") {
        if (choice2 === "scissors"){
            return "Rock wins";
        } else {
            return "Paper wins";
        }
    }
    else if (choice1 === "paper") {
        if (choice2 === "rock"){
            return "paper wins";
        } else {
            return "scissors wins";
        }
    }
}
```

So you can see, I added { after any 'ifs' without, and then added two } to close those in the correct spots.

Answer (score -2):

```
 else {
    return "Paper wins";
}
else if (choice1 === "paper") {
```

you cannot do a else if after doing a else;

I was negated by not giving the full answer and force him to study conditions?